# How to count write the linq query when the grouped bY column is in one table and the items are in another table

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to write this simple Linq query without success. Here's the original SQL Query:

```
SELECT os.OSName, COUNT(d.DOperatingSystemId)
FROM [dbo].[Device_OperatingSystem] os
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Device_DeviceDetails] d
ON os.OperatingSystemID = d.DOperatingSystemId
GROUP BY os.OSName
```

Which return result like:

```
Windows     131
Linux         7
iOS          51
```

This is my linq query:

```
public List<KeyValue> GetNumberOFDevicesByOperatingSystem()
{
   var numberOFDevicesByOperatingSystem = new List<KeyValue>();
   var rawQuery = GetAll()
       .GroupBy(
        os => os.OSName,
        os => os.Devices,
            (key, g) => new { key, g });

  foreach (var item in rawQuery)
  {
     numberOFDevicesByOperatingSystem.Add(new KeyValue
     {
         Key = item.key,
         Value = item.g.Count().ToString()
     });
  }

  return numberOFDevicesByOperatingSystem.ToList();
}
```

This return the following result:

```
Windows     1
Linux       1
iOS         1
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Please show us how `GetAll()` is implemented.

Comment: Try `GetAll().Select(os => new { key = os.Name, count = os.Devices.Count()});`  if you want the count of `Devices`, no need for a group by.

Comment: @juharr That assumes there's a foreign key set up.

Comment: there's a FK between Device and OS table, so @juharr response worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
var osDevicesList = (
    from os in context.Device_OperatingSystem

    let devicesWithOSCount = (
        from d in context.Device_DeviceDetails
        where d.DOperatingSystemId == os.OperatingSystemID
        select d.Id
    ).Count()

    group devicesWithOSCount by os.OSName into g

    select new {
        OS = g.Key,
        value = g.First()
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return (from d in Device_DeviceDetails
group d by d.DOperatingSystemId into dddg
join os in Device_OperatingSystem on dddg.Key equals os.OperatingSystemID
select new KeyValue { Key = os.OSName, Value = dddg.Count()}).ToList();
```